# Reset position of SELECTED Object after clicking Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, drag, event-listener

I'm trying to reset the position of my latest Object in three.js.

First of all I have this:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

            event.preventDefault();
            var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 0.5 );
            projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

            var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

            if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

                controls.enabled = false;

                SELECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;

                container.style.cursor = 'move';

                //mouse Click goes here
                buildMenu();

            }

        }
```

In my buildMenu Function I position my Object like this:

```
function buildMenu(){
                camera.position.set(0,60,250);                  


                //HERE I POSITION MY SELECTED OBJECT

                SELECTED.position.x = 0;
                SELECTED.position.y = 50;
                SELECTED.position.z = 200;

                $(document).bind('click',function(){
                    $(document).click(function(){
                        scene.remove(overlayBG);

                     **//HERE I TRY TO RESET EVERYTHING BUT NOTHING WORKS : (**

                        });
                });

                //$('#bg, #menu').fadeIn(100)

            }
```

I thought I can easily reset my Object by mesh.position.set(0,0,0) inside the $(document).click Function but that doesn't work. How can I detect the latest (Re-Positioned) Object and how can I reposition it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly.

Made a simple example, You don't need to bind any click events for this. [Example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/YFkMy/26/)

```
//last selected object
 if ( SELECTED ){
    SELECTED.position.set(0,0,0);
} 
//new selected object
SELECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
```

Comment: Thank you uhura, that helps : ) But if I try to position something else as the SELECTED e.g. my mesh, it says it is not defined, can you give me a hint?

Comment: If your variable in function is local then outside the function it will be undefined. You can update an example to show your problem.

Comment: Hey Uhura, here is the link [link](http://holy-crab.de/WebGL/sites/shop.html) If you click on the cube it alert the name. Idea is to click on one board and the board moves towards the camera and on click next to the board it moves to it's original place again. The Cube is only a placeholder. Thanks